# IPython 0.13: autoreloading modules every time I enter a command?

Tags: python, ipython

Say I have a script that imports various modules in Python.

```
import my_module
from some_other_module import foo
...
```

I then run this script from IPython.

Say I make changes to the function `bar` in  `my_module` and  `foo` in `some_other_module`.

Say that I now want to interactively call either `my_module.bar()` or `foo()` from my IPython session.

1. Is there a way to have IPython automatically reload every loaded module when I invoke a command before executing the command?
2. If not automatically, how can I reload every loaded module manually in IPython without having to explicitly name the module?
3. Finally, is there a way to set up my IPython session in my `ipython_config.py` (startup file) so that it supports this functionality off-the-shelf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a `%load_ext autoreload` followed by a `%autoreload?` to see how to use it.

You can also have a look at `InteractiveShellApp.extensions` and `InteractiveShellApp.extra_extension` configuration options for extension at startup.

Finally, you can also add a `.py` file in your IPython profile dir (`$ ipython locate` to get it), put it in  the `startup` subfolder, it will be executed at startup time.

There is a restriction though, C modules cannot be reloaded.